# How do I set json file(json file's path) to a value in Azure App settings?

Tags: firebase, azure, azure-web-app-service, firebase-admin, azure-app-configuration

How do I set json file(json file's path) to a value in Azure App settings?

I am adding Firebase SDK to the server.

I defined "/my-json-file.json" as GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS key's value.

[image]

Because "/" means "\site\wwwroot" (root directory).

But it didn't worked. I define encironment variable in my desktop, 

so i checked completely in local environment.

I have to make it work at the production, test, etc environment too.

Is there any information about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To set JSON content type for key-values, we need to add  the JSON values in `Azure App Configuration` =>  `Configuration Explorer` Section.

[image]

***Check the below workaround for creating and consuming JSON key-values***

In `Azure Portal` => `App Configurations` => `Create`

- Make sure you have a valid JSON content type. I have added `application/json` content type.

We can create JSON key-values from Azure portal, Azure CLI or even you can create a json file and import values.

Here I have created from portal => App Configuration => Configuration Explorer

[image]

***Consume JSON values in WebApp***

Create ASP. Net Core App, navigate to the project root directory and run the below command to add the `UserSecretID`

```cs
dotnet user-secrets init
```

Install the `Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore` NuGet Package

My `Program.cs`

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
{    
    builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(connectionString);
})
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddControllersWithViews();
            });

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

- Now we need to display the values which we have stored in Azure App Configuration

***My Index.html of Home Controller***

```cs
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: @Configuration["Settings:BackgroundColor"]
    }

    h1 {
        color: @Configuration["Settings:FontColor"];
        font-size: @Configuration["Settings:FontSize"]px;
    }
</style>

<h1>@Configuration["Settings:Message"]</h1>
```

I have set Background color as yellow in JSON values, you can see it is applied.

***Output:***

[image]

Refer the official  [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern) for binding hierarchical configuration data.